# SQL query based on aggregate and join

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL and I am trying to join two tables by performing aggregate and join functions. I am using `Orderdetails` and `PurchaseOrderDetails` tables to join based on `OrderID`.

I want to compare the sum on quantity in the `OrderDetails` table and sum on quantity in the `PurchaseOrderDetails` table and `sum(PurchaseOrderDetails.quantity) != sum(OrderDetails.quantity)` based on particular `orderID` and also join them based on `orderID`.

I have following two tables:

`OrderDetails` table design

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [lineID]
      ,[orderID]
      ,[itemNumber]
      ,[itemDesc]
      ,[qty]
      ,[price]
      ,[priceType]
      ,[contract]
      ,[supplierPartID]
      ,[uom]
      ,[classDomain]
      ,[classValue]
      ,[comments]
      ,[shipping]
      ,[tax]
      ,[reqDeliveryDate]
      ,[fillInfo]
      ,[invoiceID]
      ,[Version]
      ,[productid]
      ,[eta]
      ,[lineOrderID]
  FROM [bfdb].[dbo].[OrderDetails]
```

and `PurchaseOrderDetails` table design is:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [podID]
      ,[poID]
      ,[distPN]
      ,[mfrID]
      ,[itemNumber]
      ,[itemName]
      ,[qty]
      ,[price]
      ,[invoiceID]
      ,[orderID]
      ,[itemReceived]
      ,[qtyReceived]
      ,[distConf]
      ,[distFillStatus]
      ,[distLastUpdate]
      ,[distTracking]
      ,[distFillDesc]
      ,[Version]
      ,[productid]
      ,[lineOrderID]
  FROM [bfdb].[dbo].[PurchaseOrderDetails]
```

I tried the following query but getting the incorrect result. Suppose if it has 1 row in the `OrderDetails` table and 2 rows in the `PurchaseOrderDetails`, then the sum for `OrderDetails` becomes double after joining. Same with 1 row in `PurchaseOrderDetails` table if I have more than 1 row in `OrderDetails` table for that

```
SELECT
    od.orderID, SUM(pod.qty) as Totalqty, SUM(od.qty) as od_qty
FROM
    PurchaseOrderDetails pod
INNER JOIN 
    OrderDetails od ON od.orderID = pod.orderID AND pod.orderID = 15506
GROUP BY
    od.orderID
```

Here is the snapshot of my data

[image: PurchaseOrderDetails]

[image: OrderDetails]

Comment: I have removed the mysql and sql-server database tags it is unlikely that you are using both please only tag the rdbms that you are using.  Also include data and desired result in your question rather than linking an image don't make the community do the work of building temp tables etc.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the non-standard syntax used and the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first `sum` the quantities by `orderid` for each of these two tables separately and then join. Try this:

```
select od.orderID, pod.qty as Totalqty, od.qty as od_qty
from (
    select orderid, sum(pod.qty) as qty
    from PurchaseOrderDetails
    group by orderid
) pod
inner join (
    select orderid, sum(pod.qty) as qty
    from OrderDetails
    group by orderid
) od on od.orderid = pod.orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply change the AND condition to a WHERE clause, try this code below:

```
SELECT od.orderID, SUM(pod.qty) as Totalqty, SUM(od.qty) as od_qty FROM PurchaseOrderDetails pod INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON od.orderID = pod.orderID WHERE pod.orderID = 15506 GROUP BY od.orderID
```

Comment: This won't make any difference to the results.. the condition `pod.orderID = 15506` should be in the `where` clause where it really belongs in this case.. `having` should be used to filter based on aggregated fields..

Comment: My bad, I was gonna say a where clause and then I thought it was a summarized field. Thanks for correcting me. :)